# Laravel + Vue ssr. Prefetch data

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-ssr

I'm trying to make application lavevel + vue with server side render. I have found this [manual](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/11/27/vue-js-laravel-server-side-rendering-router/) and it works perfect. Bu there is a small problem. I need fetch data before page loading for SEO issues and I found [official vue ssr manual](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/data.html) for prefetch. But it does not work. I only see error in the console
`entry-client.js:6952 [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app`.

my `entry-server.js`

```
import {createApp} from './app'
export default context => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const {app, router, store} = createApp();
router.push(context.url)

router.onReady(() => {
  // This `rendered` hook is called when the app has finished rendering
  context.rendered = () => {
    context.state = store.state
  }

  resolve(app)
}, reject)
}).then(app => {
renderVueComponentToString(app, (err, res) => {
  print(res);
});
})
.catch((err) => {
  print(err);
})
}
```

Are there any idea how solve this problem?

Looks like `Promise` does not work

Laravel 5.7 and Vue 2.6.6

Comment: Do you have id="app" on your root? Maybe it's your problem

Comment: @ИльяОсманов I have

Comment: Hi @TDev, did you work this out? i'm pulling my hair over similar issue

Comment: @Klon It doesn't work anyway :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do final state injection with Vue SRR with V8Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62192057/how-to-do-final-state-injection-with-vue-srr-with-v8js)